# Is there a way to update just one file in microsoft azure without having to redeploy everything?

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am making a web app with python and running it on azure. It the program creates jsons and stores them. If I want to update the program is there a way to just redeploy the main python file so that it doesnt overwrite all of the josn files stored on the server?

Comment: Are you saying that the python program creates json files and stores them in the app service? If that’s the case I would suggest sorting the data elsewhere like Azure Storage Account (blob container).

Answer (score 0):

You could update the file using FileZilla or some other FTP client. The publish profile contains the info you need.  Download the publish profile from the app service overview blade, open it in Notepad, pull out the FTP address, username, and password, and import those into FileZilla. Then just drag the file across.

Comment: When i download firezilla and do that it does not show me the correct files. It gives me stuff like ASP.net, data and DeploymentLogStream. Not the actual files running the site. If I access it with ssh in vsc it shows the corect files when i use ls in the terminal. how do I get the files I want?

Comment: your content will be in the site/wwwroot folder. Might be different in a Linux app service but it'll still be there somewhere.

Comment: 'your content will be in the site/wwwroot folder' it is not in there. There is just hostingstart.html, oryx-manifest.toml and output.tar.gz in there. I have checked every singe folder and file in there.